# String search between DataFrame columns that matches a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have one table that contains strings

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"strings_to_search" : ["AA1 BB2 CVC GF2","AR1 KP1","PL3 4OR 91K GZ3"]})
```

and one with search parameters as regular expressions

```
re = pd.DataFrame({"regex_search" : ["^(?=.*AA1).*$", "^(?=.*AR1)(?=.*PL3).*$", "^(?=.*4OR)(?=.*GZ3).*$"]})
```

My goal is to match the string to the search parameter if it is part of the string.
I want to compare each string to each pattern and join the string-pattern that match like this:

```
| AA1 BB2 CVC GF2 | ^(?=.*AA1).*$
| PL3 4OR 91K GZ3 | ^(?=.*4OR)(?=.*GZ3).*$
```

Is there any way do do this in pandas? I have implemented something similar in sparkSQL using the rlike function but spark does not do too well when joining large tables.

Since pandas does not have an rlike function my approach was to do a crossjoin of both tables and then compare the columns.

```
a["key"] = 0
re["key"] = 0
res = a.merge(re, on="key")
```

But how do I search column strings_to_search with the regex in column regex_search?

Comment: Do you want to check your string with only the corresponding regex or all the regex?

Comment: I'd like to find the regex that matches and join it to the string

Comment: do you care about speed? if not my answer should work for you.

Comment: @Daniel I've tried to answer. Let me know if my answer is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare each string with each regex use list comprehension and re.match:

```
import re
result = [string+' | '+reg for reg in r['regex_search'] for string in a['strings_to_search']
          if re.compile(reg).match(string)]
result
['AA1 BB2 CVC GF2|^(?=.*AA1).*$', 'PL3 4OR 91K GZ3|^(?=.*4OR)(?=.*GZ3).*$']
```

If you want a new dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'matches': result })
new_df
         matches
0   AA1 BB2 CVC GF2|^(?=.*AA1).*$
1   PL3 4OR 91K GZ3|^(?=.*4OR)(?=.*GZ3).*$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine your Dataframe then use an `apply` function to perform the regular expression search.  I've renamed your `re` DataFrame to `r` in this example since `re` is the name of a module.  First perform a cartesian product of the the two DataFrames.  Then in the `lambda` the regular expression, `regex_search`, is evaluated in each row and a boolean output indicating if the search yields `True` if the expression existis in `strings_to_search` or `False` if the expression doesn't exist.  Finally, filter the DataFrame to where matches occur, group on `strings_to_search` and generate a list of all matching `regex_search`.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

a["idx"] = 1
r["idx"] = 1
df = a.merge(r, on="idx").drop("idx", axis=1)

df["output"] = df.apply(lambda x: bool(re.compile(x["regex_search"]).search(x["strings_to_search"])), axis=1)

df[df["output"] == True].groupby("strings_to_search")["regex_search"].apply(list)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortionately concat does not work here because I do not only have to check the corresponding regex but all of them. When apply the code for "df["output"] to a crossjoined df I get an error 
TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Ah, okay that requirement wasn't clear in the OP.  I've updated the answer to include a cartesian join at the beginning to make sure all regex are searched.  Then I've added a `groupby` to summarize all the positive matches for each string you want searched.

Answer (score 0):

this will get you result but slow.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({"strings_to_search" : ["AA1 BB2 CVC GF2","AR1 KP1","PL3 4OR 91K GZ3"]})
b = pd.DataFrame({"regex_search" : ["^(?=.*AA1).*$", "^(?=.*AR1)(?=.*PL3).*$", "^(?=.*4OR)(?=.*GZ3).*$"]})

a.insert(1,'regex','')

for item in b.regex_search:
    for s in a.strings_to_search:
        if(re.match(item,s)):
            a.regex.loc[a.strings_to_search == s] = item

print(a)
```